# Why does a method parameter cause NotSerializableException with Mockito?

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, mockito

I have some Scala code which runs with spark, but I simplified them:

```
// Not Serializable
class Config

object FileReader extends FileReader
class FileReader extends Serializable {
  def read(config: Config): String = config.getClass.toString
}

object Task extends Task(FileReader)
class Task(fileReader: FileReader) extends Serializable {
  def execute(config: Config): Unit = {
    fileReader.read(config)
  }
}
```

Not the `Config` is not `Serializable`.

I want to write some tests for them, and the instance of `Task` need to be `Serializable` because it may be serialized and send to spark workers.

I use this function to check if an object can be serialized or not:

```
def checkSerializable(obj: AnyRef, name: String) = {
  println("### checking " + name + ": " + obj.getClass)
  new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()).writeObject(obj)
  println(name + " ok")
}
```

First let's check if a normal `Task` instance can be serialized:

```
val task = new Task(new FileReader)
checkSerializable(task, "no-mockito")
```

Outputs:

```
### checking no-mockito: class Task
no-mockito ok
```

Seems OK.

But I want to mock the `FileReader` with Mockito, so my code will be:

```
val fileReader = Mockito.mock(classOf[FileReader])
val config = Mockito.mock(classOf[Config])
Mockito.when(fileReader.read(config)).thenReturn("mocked")
val task = new Task(fileReader)
checkSerializable(task, "with-mockito1")
```

It reports error that `Config` is not serializable:

```
### checking with-mockito1: class Task
java.io.NotSerializableException: Config$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$c7dcb0a5
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1359)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1155)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
```

This is strange because `config` is just some method parameters, not class fields!

I modified my code a little bit to make the `config` serializable:

```
val fileReader = Mockito.mock(classOf[FileReader])
val config = Mockito.mock(classOf[Config], Mockito.withSettings().serializable())
Mockito.when(fileReader.read(config)).thenReturn("mocked")
val task = new Task(fileReader)
checkSerializable(task, "with-mockito2")
```

It still fails, with another `NotSerializableException`:

```
### checking with-mockito2: class Task
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.mockito.internal.creation.DelegatingMethod
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
```

Not sure why `config` instance will be included in `task` when working with Mockito? And how to avoid it?

Demo project: https://github.com/freewind/mockito-serialization-issue, you can just clone it and run `demo/MockitoDemo.scala`

---

Update:

Another notable thing is: if I remove this line

```
fileReader.read(config)
```

from `Task`, that means the `Task` will be:

```
class Task(fileReader: FileReader) extends Serializable {
  def execute(config: Config): Unit = {
    // removed this line: fileReader.read(config)
  }
}
```

no `NotSerializableException` will be thrown anymore (I didn't change the testing code)

Comment: Similar question: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-test-Spark-task-with-Mockito-td22347.html

Comment: You are trying to serialise a `Task` which has been populated with a *mock* fileReader, and this mock fileReader has stored information about what it should do when its read method is called with the mock config. When you serialise that Task, the mock fileReader needs to be serialised, which won't work both because of that "when" info it is holding on to (the first failure), and because of unserialisable stuff that these mocks have anyway (the second failure). Not sure there's any way you can mix mocks and serialisation like that.

Comment: @Shadowlands, just updated my question, another strange thing

Comment: Re: the update - at that point it would appear that the mock neither holds a reference to `config` (although the `when` line in the test code shouldn't compile now, if you didn't remove it), nor the `DelegatingMethod` entity it had before. If you added any methods at all to fileReader, the latter problem would likely return.

Comment: @Shadowlands Feel like I didn't make it clear about my update, so I just updated again

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That is ... not what I would have expected.

Answer (score 17):

You probably will need to make the FileReader mock serializable too try:

```
val fileReader = Mockito.mock(classOf[FileReader], Mockito.withSettings().serializable())
```

Comment: Is there an alternate way to do the same thing using @Mock annotation?

Comment: You might be able to.  The Mock annotation looks like it supports an optional serializable boolean argument.  http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mock.html